# Email service that allows communication between anonymous emails

Tags: email

Say we work for a marketplace web portal, where we sell products from out suppliers to final customers.

We currently want to allow our customers to ask support directly from the supplier and the supplier to respond to them. Problem is we don't want either of them to know each other's email.

Also, we want to be in the loop of the conversation at all times, to oversee issues are being resolved and even (but not a minimum requirement) step in the conversation occasionally.

And either it has to work with gmail or worst case scenario, and external app.

Some ticketing services would theoretically allow to do something like this if we imported the supplier's contacts and pretended they are "agents", same as our workers who solve tickets. The problems with this is we'd have hundreds of agents and these services usually charge per agent, so that's a big no-no.

I'm currently talking with Zoho and Zendesk sales and tech teams see if they can arrange something like that, but it doesn't look like it's going too well.

There's many marketplaces out there that use generated email addresses to do this. So say as a customer I paid for a hotel in booking.com and I need to ask a question to the hotel or cancel last minute. I'll send my message through a form, and in a day I'll receive an email from the address jih18jkh1201jsgfj5jkn6jk2j3n66jknkno@booking.com - this is actually an email from the supplier, not from booking, although I expect booking is aware of the whole email conversation.
With this example I don't say I need this implementation as any sort of requirement, but I'm simply pointing out this may be a solution that I just don't know where to find and who to buy it from.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.